# Hooking to empty C++ implementation with C++/CLI events

Tags: c++-cli, vtk

I am using an open source toolkit (VTK) that has an object with a method that is triggered by pressing any key. The idea is to overwrite the implementation in your own class but I can't figure out how to do it in C++/CLI.

This is what I have, but I can't figure out how to hook it to an object.

```
delegate void myEventHandler(vtkObject * sender, EventArgs ^ e);
event myEventHandler^ LeftButtonPressEvt;

LeftButtonPressEvt += gcnew myEventHandler(&MyClass::MyModifiedOnKeyPress);

void MyModifiedOnKeyPress(vtkObject * sender, EventArgs ^ e)
{ 
    //this should be called whenever the button is pressed 
}
```

Hooking it to the vtk object would look something like this:

```
vtkObject->OnKeyPress += gcnew myEventHandler(&MyClass::Pick);
```

This returns the error that a function is the left operand which makes sense, but I cant figure out how this would be hooked to the event.

Answer (score 0):

For non-static methods, you need to specify which object the delegate should point to.

```
vtkObject->OnKeyPress += gcnew myEventHandler(this, &MyClass::Pick);
//                                            ^^^^
```

<sub>(If that doesn't solve the problem, then I don't understand exactly what problem you're having. If you're getting an error message, don't describe the error, copy & paste *exactly* what the error message is.)</sub>

Comment: Sadly there is no error message, making this difficult to describe.

Comment: Maybe you could describe more verbosely what's going on. What are you trying to do, what is your expected result, what is your actual result?